# No active compatible AVD's or devices found. --- getting this message only for SAMSUNG Devices

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-sdk-2.3

I am new in android development. I have downloaded [Android SDK + eclipse](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). and did the settings as mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html). I am using two mobile sets `i) Micromax canvas A11` and `ii) SAMSUNG Galaxy S3`. For Micromax it is working properly. I can able to run my `hello world` application in micromax. But same app is not working in `SAMSUNG`. It gives me this error message

```
[2014-06-09 13:03:14 - SamsungOne] No active compatible AVD's or devices found. Relaunch this configuration after connecting a device or starting an AVD.
```

what to do... please help. And  I have to develop application for `SAMSUNG S3` only. And I referred other posts of stackoverflow. but getting the same error.

In device manager it is showing like this ....
[image]

Comment: what is `minSdkVersion` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`? and OS of your device?

Comment: Have you installed samsung kies in your pc?

Comment: `android:minSdkVersion="8"  android:targetSdkVersion="19" />`

Comment: @shylendra.. No i have not installed. Shall i install it ?

Comment: yes see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run your applications in samsung mobiles you need to install samsung kies in your PC. Download kies from [here](http://samsung-kies.en.softonic.com/)

Some devices will automatically installs device drivers in your pc when you connect to pc but some are not. So that is why we need to install pc sync to test our applications.

**To enable USB debugging (only for Android v4.2 and above) :**

Go to Settings → More → About Device Scroll down to Build Number Tap it repeatedly (tap 7 times). See the Developer options menu under Settings → More

See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cL1U0MK2E9U) video for installing kies and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6FkhSeiYd8&hd=1) for enable debug mode.

Comment: did got the solution?

Comment: device is not connecting to kies

Comment: have you installed it properly?

Comment: yes.. I think so.. I followed all the instructions. I have updated my answer

Comment: have you enabled debug mode in your samsung mobile by goging to 
    Go to Settings → More → About Device
    Scroll down to Build Number
    Tap it repeatedly (tap 7 times).
    See the Developer options menu under Settings → More

Comment: You have to install the driver, and the easiest way is installing kies. But after that, you can (and should) uninstall kies without uninstalling the driver.

Comment: In that case, in my experience, KIES is just bloatware that does nothing, and doesn't fix the problem that a Samsung device isn't properly detected in Windows 7 without going through loops.

Comment: @shylendra.. Got the answer.. Posted. Thanks for supporting :)

Comment: @shylendra.. I updated one line in your answer. Please review and accept it

Comment: @D'Scolz I can't able to approve my own post. There is no option to accept your edit.see http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5040359

Answer (score 1):

Please Enable your Debuging mode on in your device,
To Enable to debugging mode >> go to Developer option in settings

And Download Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver from here
http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows

Hope it will worked for you

Answer (score 1):

My Samsung is an honest piece of.... er, brick, considering it doesn't even properly connect to USB anymore. Beforehand, when it didn't think it's charging when it isn't, and think that my computer is a car dock; I had to manually link it to the PC so that it would be detected. The way you do that is by downloading the drivers, specifically this one: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2645355

What also helped was installing these drivers using the command 'pnputil -i -a filename.inf'
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1514942

And what you need to do is, restart your computer, then when you plug the device in, it will detect it as an UNKNOWN DEVICE because Samsung Drivers are terrible. When this happens, go to Control Panel -> Device Manager -> Other Devices -> Unknown Device -> Update Driver Software -> Browse my computer -> Let me pick from a list -> See all drivers -> Samsung -> select the one for usb phones.

That should fix the problem. KIES never helps.

Comment: k i am trying kies now. already installed. if its not works then i wll follow you

Comment: I tried it but still getting the same error... help :(

Comment: Which driver did you select from the list for the Unknown Device?

Comment: I that list there were two drivers with same name `MTP Driver`

Comment: Okay, uninstall that driver in the device manager. What you want to assign to it is something called SAMSUNG Electronics Co., Ltd --> SAMSUNG Android ADB Interface Version 2.9.5.916.

Answer (score 1):

**Got it..**

In your mobile Goto

```
Setting -> About -> (touch on Build Number 7 times continuously) -> then come back to Developer Option -> Enable USB Debugging
```

`USB Debugging` option was not coming for me. Above Android v4.2 they have hidden `USB Debugging` option.

Got this from [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6FkhSeiYd8&hd=1)

Comment: That was not obvious.

Comment: But I dont know... After that only its working properly